# How to find dimension of a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For instance, take $S=\{\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^5:\;v_1+v_2+v_3=0,\;v_1+v_2+v_5=0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^5.$ How would I go about finding $\dim S?$ I can see that both $v_1+v_2+v_3=0,\;v_1+v_2+v_5=0$ define four-dimensional subspaces, but I am not sure how to "put them together". Could I say $\dim S\geq 4$ but say, $(1\;1\;1\;1\;1)^{\text{T}}\not\in S$ so we cannot have $\dim S =5$, so $\dim S=4?$

I then need to do the same for $T=\{\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^5:\;v_3=v_4=v_5, \;v_1+v_2=0\}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the general way to find the dimension is to find a set of linearly independent vectors that span your space (i.e any vector in your space can be written as a combination of constant multiples of that list).   If your list both spans and is independent, then the length is the dimension

Answer (score 1):

Define $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1& 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1& 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$,
then $S = \ker A$. It is easy to compute $\dim {\cal R} A$, and the standard
formula gives $\dim \ker A = 5-\dim {\cal R} A$.

You can figure out a basis for $S$ by inspection of $A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the second subspace, would I use $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0& 1 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ then?

Comment: Looks good to me.